# Correct approach for accepting multiple function signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is a seemingly simple issue, but I'm having issues finding an appropiate approach.

On the most basic level, I'm trying to create an input that validates it's value. The component would take an array of validator functions and apply them to determine if the user input is acceptable, as such:

```
interface ValidatedInputProps {
  validatorFunctions: GenericValidatorFunction[]
}

export const ValidatedInput = (props : ValidatedInputProps) : React.ReactElement => {........}
```

The validator functions always take a single argument (the value of the input) and always return a boolean (either a valid input, or not)

```
export const isEmailFormat: GenericValidatorFunction = (input: string): boolean => {
  const pattern = /^.+@.+$/;
  return pattern.test(input);
};
export const isNumberOdd: GenericValidatorFunction = (input: number): boolean => {
  return Boolean(input % 2);
};
```

The issue is how to actually type the `GenericValidatorFunction` signature:
Naive aproaches such as

```
export type GenericValidatorFunction = ((arg0: string) => boolean) | ((arg0: number) => boolean);
```

or

```
export type GenericValidatorFunction = (arg0: string | number) => boolean;
```

and variations obviously don't work due to the incompatibility of string and number type, and give error messages as `Argument of type ‘string | number’ is not assignable to parameter of type ‘string’`or `Argument of type ‘string’ is not assignable to parameter of type ‘never’`.

I understand *why* this doesn't work, and suspect a more complex signature with generics is probably the aproach. Or maybe I'm going about this in a completely wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you planning to use an undifferentiated array of these things for the `validatorFunctions` property of your interface?   Do you have some ordered tuple of input types somewhere?

Comment: The implementation is going to be something like

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const setIsValid(validation.every((validatorFunction) => validatorFunction(value)));
  };

Comment: Uh, but `HTMLInputElement["value"]` is always a *`string`*, never a `number`.  Why would you ever pass a function expecting a `number`?  Your `isNumberOdd` should ideally be something like `(i: string) => Boolean(Number(i) % 2)` and you can forget all about whatever you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use generics in this case, like:

```
export type GenericValidatorFunction<T> = (arg0: T) => boolean;
```

And then:

```
export const isNumberOdd: GenericValidatorFunction<number> = (input: number): boolean => {
  return Boolean(input % 2);
};
```

Comment: this will not work since the provided input can be of either type `string` or `number`, and a function like this does not handle the `string` case.

Comment: You can also use strings in this way: `GenericValidatorFunction<string>`

Comment: you're missing the point. Try your "isNumberOdd" function with a string input. You need to handle both cases with union types or function overloads. See my answer.

Comment: No, this actually seems to be what I'm looking for. Going to give it a bit more of a through test and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to validate the input which can be of types either `string` or `number`, you will need to handle both cases in all validator functions.

You can thus either

a) use union types in your validator functions

```
function validateIsBob(input: string | number): boolean {
  return typeof input === "string"
           ? input === "bob"
           : false;
}
```

b) use function overloading (e.g. https://mariusschulz.com/blog/function-overloads-in-typescript)

```
function validateIsBob(input: string): boolean {
  return string === "bob";
}

function validateIsBob(input: number): boolean {
  return false;
}
```

---

I assume here that your logic will require at least 1 validator to pass, not all of them, because the latter is logically impossible, right?

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I don't have a a single function with multiple possible signatures, for which overloading would be correct, I have many functions with many signatures, so I need an encompassing function signature.